# How to use elasticsearch to get JOIN functionality as in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, elasticsearch

I have an SQL query that does JOIN operations over 3-4 tables to get the data. Now we are shifting to elasticsearch for better performance. How can I replicate the same JOIN query using elasticsearch? I have read about parent/child documents but my data doesn't have any strict parent/child kind of data.

Comment: Related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254523/sql-on-elastic-search/57299844#57299844

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not support JOINs, that's the whole purpose of [NoSQL technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) in the first place. There are ways to create some relationships between your data using [parent/child relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html) (as you've noticed), [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/nested-objects.html) and also using a special [terms lookup optimization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup), but that's about it.

However, in order to take the most out of Elasticsearch, the main idea is to [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html) your data as much as possible and store self-contained documents. This means that you can take a single document and it contains all the info it needs. You don't care about the fact that data is going to be duplicated.

For instance, suppose you have the following JOIN query in your SQL database for retrieving all people with their address, city and country (i.e. 4 tables):

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, 
       a.street_name, a.street_num,
       c.name, c2.name
  FROM person p
  JOIN address a ON a.id = p.addr_id
  JOIN city c ON c.id = p.city_id
  JOIN country c2 ON c2.id = p.country_id
```

In Elasticsearch, you would create a document containing exactly the fields that are returned by the above query, i.e.

```
 {
     "first_name": "John",
     "last_name": "Doe",
     "street_num": 34,
     "street_name": "Main Street",
     "city": "San Francisco",
     "country": "United States"
 }
```

So, one way to see this, is that in Elasticsearch you're going to store the same (or very similar) set of fields that you would get as a result of running your query in your relational database.

Taking the step from RDBMS to Elasticsearch is a paradigm shift. If you are ever going to take that step, you need to think different in terms of your data.

Comment: Thanks! I agree elasticsearch works in a way very different from RDBMS queries. But right now we are in a phase of shifting from RDBMS to ES and want our solution to work with the existing data. Storing the fields that we want as a result of our queries is a nice solution for now.

Comment: Is that still true? "Elasticsearch does not support JOINs"

Comment: @Manroop Yes it's [still true](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/sql-syntax-select.html). There are [other ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/joining-queries.html) though