# Elasticsearch 5.1 with MySql Database

Tags: mysql, search, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I have to use elastic search in my project for searching. And I'm new player on that field. I have spend some time on it and I come to know that how it stores data and it's working etc. But I have some questions regarding Elasticsearch with MySql. Like,

- **How to index relational tables (Normalised Tables of MySql) into Elasticsearch?** I think I have two options. i.e, **(i)** index MySql tables as it is in Elasticsearch and use two search queries for searching data from both tables (say, users and contacts) while searching. **(ii)** Get all the parent and child records from MySql tables and create nested JSON and index it in Elasticsearch. But I don't think that this is  right way.
- **How to update document in Elasticsearch as MySql record changes?**
- **How to convert JOIN query of MySql into search quesry of Elasticsearch?** or I must have to make two separate search call for each table.

So there is lots of confusion in mind when topic comes with MySql. I have already searched on Internet. But I have found blogs related to only basics, not with MySql. If any one can explain this nicely, it will be appreciated.

Comment: These answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477816/how-to-use-elasticsearch-to-get-join-functionality-as-in-sql/34477920#34477920 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705

Comment: @Val. Thanks, as it really helped me to understand what I can do to achieve my requirements. But can you help me little bit more on [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/212#issuecomment-266722804) ?

Comment: You can achieve that (i.e. denormalize users/projects) with the solutions shown in the first and third links I posted above

Comment: @Val. Thanks to look at there.. I will try as you have suggested and will reply here. So other users may get help from here too.