# How to make relationship in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search i'm wondering how to store relational datas in elastic search.

For example:

```
{
 "Teacher name": "tom", 
 "Students": [{"name":"John"}, {"name":"raj"}....]
},

{
 "Teacher name": "joe", 
 "Students": [{"name":"raj"}, {"name":"jane"}....]
}
```

this is my model data, is it ok to store students in array field.
Or any better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: These answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477816/how-to-use-elasticsearch-to-get-join-functionality-as-in-sql/34477920#34477920 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705

Comment: You generally don't store relational data like that in elasticsearch. If your need is to work with relational data, then a relational database might be better. Most convenient in elasticsearch is to have all data an object needs in the object structure, like you suggest. Read more in the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html

Answer (score 1):

In Elasticsearch you have two alternative solution to map the teacher/students relationship: [nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) vs [join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) (parent/child).

If the number of students is not big you can store the students as an array of nested object, like in your example. But the drawbacks are related to the disk space consumption and of the the fact that every time you update or add a single student to an existing document: the full document is first deleted and re-indexed as a new one.

The join datatype on the other hand is more complex to use (you have to use parent child queries), but allows you to store the child in a more independent way from their parents. The join datatype is good if the number of children is high and updates and insert of children are frequent.